# Masters at a local uni or job

Tags: phd, masters

I am a final year undergraduate (Computer Science; decent uni in a third world country) and one of my long-term goals is to pursue a Ph.D. (preferably at a top 20 uni).

For some reasons, I didn't apply for Masters abroad this year. I have a decent job lined-up. I have the following choices:

1. Join the company and apply for Masters next year (Fall 2019).
2. Join a Masters program at a local uni and then apply for Ph.D. after two years.

What would be the best option? (I have some research experience but no publications yet).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in a dilemma, I would suggest that you join the company and experience it. They are usually two different things. Once you experience working for a company, you will know what is best for you. Staying in academia or not will be a rather easy choice for you.
This is something only you can know.

And if you can work it out I suggest you to find a company that allows you to do Masters while working.